# Running a query on query result? (PHP + SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have a table with 1,100,000 rows which contains user's data.

Its format is sort of like this:

```
User_Id Date Action
```

I was wondering, instead of searching each time on the whole table for the actions that were made by a specific user on a specific date by doing the following:

```
SELECT Action FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE Date=08092014 AND User_Id=5 

SELECT Action FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE Date=09092014 AND User_Id=5

SELECT Date FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE Action="Shopping" AND User_Id=5

SELECT Date FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE Action="Eating" AND User_Id=5
```

etc.

Maybe I could do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE User_Id=5
```

And on top of this query's results I could run the above queries, which I think will result a faster execution time (correct me if I'm wrong)

Do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that...but what are you asking for? Techniques? PHP code?

Comment: Actually, the whole reason a mysql server exists is to search as fast as possible on multiple columns at once. Just let the man do his job and stick with first solution. You might want to add indizes if it is to slow.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Both if possible :)

Comment: well, maybe first learn about mysql `OR` operator

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I think you did not understand what I wanted to ask, I'll rephrase it soon.

Comment: hmmm.. you are right.. sorry. Do you have a users table, not containing the data but with unique users id? We could use it to speed up the query with joins

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier that's a fictive table, I am not allowed to share the real table's data on the internet. However, this table is similar enough for me to ask the question on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all of those queries into one query using an or.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USERS_TABLE 
WHERE (Date = 09092014 OR Date = 08092014) 
AND (Action="Shopping" OR Action="Eating") 
AND User_Id = 5
```

Comment: I doubt that will reduce the execution time of queries.. am I wrong?

Comment: You'd have to test, but you could increase execution times with proper indexing of your table(s) @user3146699

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table with unique users ids. if you don't, you might consider it? How can a profile be managed if there is no single entry for a single user? anyway that's not my business, but let's just assume you have such a table, with a `unique` field with the `User_Id`

it's named `USERS` here

```
SELECT Action,Date
FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN USERS_TABLE AS Actions 
  ON (Actions.User_Id=USERS.User_Id AND Date IN (08092014,09092014))
LEFT JOIN USERS_TABLE AS Dates
  ON (Dates.User_Id=USERS.User_Id AND Action IN ("Shopping","Eating"))
WHERE USERS.User_Id=5
```

be sure to index User_Id, Date And Action since we are searching on them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a crosstab query, after I indexed the User_Id column -

```
SELECT `Date`,
SUM(IF(`Action` = 'Eating', 1, 0)) AS `Eating`,
SUM(IF(`Action` = 'Shopping', 1, 0)) AS `Shopping`
FROM `USERS_TABLE`
WHERE `User_Id` = 5
GROUP BY `Date`
```

You'll get a result like this -

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
  Date          Eating          Shopping    
+-------------+---------------+----------+
  2002-03-01               59         72  
  2002-03-02               28          0  
  2002-03-03               22         17  
  2002-03-04               36         13  
  2002-03-06               12          0  
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

For expediency I might store this data in a temp table (with a user id column). This can be modified to accept date ranges and other limitations. That gives me some additional flexibility down the line when I need to aggregate date from multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is answered by this:

```
select action, actiondate
from 
(select *
 from USERS_TABLE
 where user_id = 5) as filter
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba5e0c/3).

The derived table basically acts as the filter you describe.

Whether it would be any faster is hard to predict - I'd run it on your production system, and see what the query plan says.